# Sounds between [x] and [h]?

Tags: fricatives, frontness-backness

I am curious about in between sounds. I mean in between as in being made in different regions of the mouth. For example, [f] is between [ɸ] and [θ]. So, I want to know what sounds are between [x] and [h].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at an IPA consonant chart, the places of articulation are listed from front to back. `/x/` is a *velar* sound, pronounced with the most relevant constriction at the velum; `/h/` is (generally treated as) a *glottal* sound, pronounced with the most relevant constriction at the glottis.

In between velar and glottal are two categories on the IPA chart, *uvular* and *pharyngeal*. The voiceless fricatives in these categories are written `/χ/` and `/ħ/`, and are used in languages like Tlingit and Arabic.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Epiglottal fricative also has a dedicated symbol

Comment: @ba Separate from the pharyngeal fricative? I thought the IPA decided that pharyngeal vs epiglottal wasn't a distinction any language made (it just varied with manner of articulation) and merged them, with small-cap H being used for a trill instead.

Comment: It could be, but the IPA chart lists them both as "fricative"